# Retrieving the last n log messages with SharpSvn

Tags: .net, svn, sharpsvn

Does anyone how to retrieve the last *n* log messages from SVN using SharpSvn? I’ve been calling GetLog with an SvnRevisionRange argument but really just need the 20 most recent messages which I can’t predict on date alone. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [SvnLogArgs.Limit](http://docs.sharpsvn.net/current/html/P_SharpSvn_SvnLogArgs_Limit.htm) I think.

Comment: Almost right - this will take the FIRST n results, I need the LAST n results i.e. the most recent messages.

Comment: If you want the last n results you should reverse your revision range. (The default is HEAD:0 and you get the results the other way if you use 0:HEAD)

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to get the last N revisions. You can retreive them by combining LIMIT and RANGE.

```
# Header - Zero (DESC) , instead of Zero - Head (ASC - DEFAULT)

Dim uri As New Uri(_svnPath)
Dim logs As New Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of SvnLogEventArgs)
client.GetLog(uri, New SvnLogArgs() With { _
    .Limit = 250, _
    .Range = New SvnRevisionRange(SvnRevision.Head, SvnRevision.Zero) _
}, logs)
```